# C# Regex in XML file

Tags: c#, regex, xml

I have an XML File which contains the following String multiple times:

`<Name Area="" Title="@(String) - @(I am) - @(looking) - @(for)" ...</Name>`

What I am trying to do is to search for these Strings with regex, cut away 
@() and save the rest in a new Textfile.
I have managed to find the pattern that matches that string, count how often that pattern matches that string, but I am failing in picking and manipulating them.

I am doing all that in a Windows Form-App.

EDIT:

Morten Bork:

The only thing I have managed to do until now is to let the user choose which file to work on and where to save the new one. And it is doing that. I am just failing with my thought of using regex.

```
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    namespace Movitool
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            public static class Globals
            {
                public static string AlrFile = string.Empty;
                public static string AlrFileNeu = string.Empty;
            }

            private void btnPfadAuswahl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                using (OpenFileDialog fileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog())
                {
                    fileDialog1.Filter = "movalr files (*.movalr)|*.movalr";
                    fileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
                    fileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"Dokumente\";

                    if (fileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        Globals.AlrFile = fileDialog1.FileName;
                        txtPfad.Text = Globals.AlrFile; 
                    }
                }
            }

            private void btnStartAlr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string pattern = @"@(.*?)";
                Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);

                using (SaveFileDialog fileDialog2 = new SaveFileDialog())
                {
                    fileDialog2.InitialDirectory = @"Dokumente";
                    fileDialog2.Title = "Save File";
                    fileDialog2.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";

                    if(fileDialog2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        Globals.AlrFileNeu = fileDialog2.FileName;
                    }
                }

                foreach(string Line in File.ReadLines(Globals.AlrFile))                     
                {
                    File.AppendAllText(Globals.AlrFileNeu, Line + Environment.NewLine);     
                }

                lblStatus.Text = "Fertig!";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using RegEx to search the XML?  It'd be better, IMO, to dump the XML into an `XDocument`, extract the strings (in your snippet they're the value for the Title attribute) into a collection and then do the RegEx over the strings in the collection.

Comment: You need to show what you have tried, provide enough code to replicate your issue, etc. Please a look at the "How to ask a question" segment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);

            string pattern = @"(?'start'@\()(?'middle'[^\)]+)(?'end'\))";

            string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "${middle}");

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output using your data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<Alarms>
<AlarmList>
<Alarm>
<Name Device="" Variable="" Area="1" ThresholdExclusive="0" Enabled="1" OnQualityGood="1" VariableDuration="0" EnableVariable="" EnableDispMsg="" Hysteresis="0" EventsCache="1024"></Name>
<ThresholdList>
<Threshold>
<Name Area="" Title="My - Searched - String" Help="" DurationFormat="" ReadAccessLevel="4294901760" WriteAccessLevel="4294901760">On</Name>
<Execution Condition="2" Threshold="1" ThresholdVar="" ThresholdLow="0" ThresholdVarLow="" VariableStatus="" Severity="10" SeverityVar="" SecDelay="0" RunCommandAtServer="0"/>
<Commands/>
<CommandsOn/>
<CommandsAck/>
<CommandsReset/>
<CommandsOff/>
<Style BackColor="4294967295" TextColor="65535" BlinkBackColor="4294967295" BlinkTextColor="4294967295" Print="1" Log="1" BlinkOnNewAlarm="0" VarTimeStamp="0" SupportAck="0" SupportReset="0" SupportResetConditionOn="0" BmpFile="" SndFile="" BeepEnabled="0" SpeechEnabled="0" RepeatSpeechEverySec="0" EnableSpeechVariable="" PlaysoundContinuosly="0" CommentOnAck="0"/>
<Recipient Attachment="" DispatchingText=""/>
<SendEmail SendON="0" SendACK="0" SendRESET="0" SendOFF="0"/>
<SendVoice SendON="0" SendACK="0" SendRESET="0" SendOFF="0"/>
<SendSMS SendON="0" SendACK="0" SendRESET="0" SendOFF="0"/>
<SendFax SendON="0" SendACK="0" SendRESET="0" SendOFF="0"/>
<SendAdminAlert SendON="0" SendACK="0" SendRESET="0" SendOFF="0"/>
<SendMessenger SendON="0" SendACK="0" SendRESET="0" SendOFF="0"/>
<ScriptCode StartSel="0" SelLength="0" OutStatusBar="1" OutLog="1" OutPrinter="1">
</ScriptCode>
</Threshold>
</ThresholdList>
</Alarm>
</AlarmList>
</Alarms>
```

Here are just the changed titles using xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            string pattern = @"(?'start'@\()(?'middle'[^\)]+)(?'end'\))";

            foreach(XElement xTitle in doc.Descendants("Name").Where(x => x.Attribute("Title") != null))
            {
                string title = (string)xTitle.Attribute("Title");
                Console.WriteLine("Title : " + Regex.Replace(title, pattern, "${middle}"));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but my problem with that is that i dont know how the strings look like, they are always different.

Comment: Did you try the code?  I'm just removing the "@(" and the closing ")".  I just tested with you string.  The input can be anything.

Comment: Yes, I have to iterate through the file where before and after my searched string are other attributes.

Comment: Apparently you did not try the code,  If you did you would see it works.  I think you need to read the documentation on RegEx to really understand what I did : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: I updated my code with your xml file.  The code works.  Look at my output.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the last comment of jdweng:

Yes i have tried your code. I tried to mix it with the answer from Tim too, who says to use XDocument.
What i have tried now is that:

```
            XmlReader xr = new XmlTextReader(Globals.AlrFile);

            lblMatches.Text = "";
            while (xr.Read())
            {
                if(xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    if(xr.AttributeCount > 0)
                    {
                        while(xr.MoveToNextAttribute())
                        {
                            string input = Convert.ToString(xr.Value);
                            string pattern = @"(?'start'@\()(?'middle'[^\)]+)(?'end'\))";
                            string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "${middle}");

                            File.AppendAllText(Globals.AlrFileNeu, output + Environment.NewLine);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            xr.Close();
```

But my input from the xml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<Alarms>
<AlarmList>
<Alarm>
<Name Device="" Variable="" Area="1" ThresholdExclusive="0" Enabled="1" OnQualityGood="1" VariableDuration="0" EnableVariable="" EnableDispMsg="" Hysteresis="0" EventsCache="1024"></Name>
<ThresholdList>
<Threshold>
<Name Area="" Title="@(My) - @(Searched) - @(String)" Help="" DurationFormat="" ReadAccessLevel="4294901760" WriteAccessLevel="4294901760">On</Name>
<Execution Condition="2" Threshold="1" ThresholdVar="" ThresholdLow="0" ThresholdVarLow="" VariableStatus="" Severity="10" SeverityVar="" SecDelay="0" RunCommandAtServer="0"/>
<Commands/>
<CommandsOn/>
<CommandsAck/>
<CommandsReset/>
<CommandsOff/>
<Style BackColor="4294967295" TextColor="65535" BlinkBackColor="4294967295" BlinkTextColor="4294967295" Print="1" Log="1" BlinkOnNewAlarm="0" VarTimeStamp="0" SupportAck="0" SupportReset="0" SupportResetConditionOn="0" BmpFile="" SndFile="" BeepEnabled="0" SpeechEnabled="0" RepeatSpeechEverySec="0" EnableSpeechVariable="" PlaysoundContinuosly="0" CommentOnAck="0"/>
<Recipient Attachment="" DispatchingText=""/>
<SendEmail SendON="0" SendACK="0" SendRESET="0" SendOFF="0"/>
<SendVoice SendON="0" SendACK="0" SendRESET="0" SendOFF="0"/>
<SendSMS SendON="0" SendACK="0" SendRESET="0" SendOFF="0"/>
<SendFax SendON="0" SendACK="0" SendRESET="0" SendOFF="0"/>
<SendAdminAlert SendON="0" SendACK="0" SendRESET="0" SendOFF="0"/>
<SendMessenger SendON="0" SendACK="0" SendRESET="0" SendOFF="0"/>
<ScriptCode StartSel="0" SelLength="0" OutStatusBar="1" OutLog="1" OutPrinter="1">
</ScriptCode>
</Threshold>
</ThresholdList>
</Alarm>
</AlarmList>
</Alarms>
```

And the Ouptut that i get in my new Text file is that:

```
1
0
1
1
0


0
1024

My - Searched - String


4294901760
4294901760
2
1

0


10

0
0
4294967295
65535
4294967295
4294967295
1
1
0
0
0
0
0


0
0
0

0
0


0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
```

And my problem is that i only need the Text in between of the Title attribute and I have multiple Alarm Elements to go through.

Comment: You do not need to use XDocument.  You are appending the results onto the original results and getting a mess.  Look at the results I posted above.